# Since googlesheets changed to V8 runtime none of my scripts work. How do I open sheet to todays date and back up sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, v8

It looks like all my googlesheets have been updated to V8 runtime however now none of my scripts work.
I need to back up my googlesheets daily and this script is just failing.
I need to open on todays date and jump to todays date.
Please can anyone help?

Comment: Hi ! What do you mean by *I need to open todays date and jump to todays date*? Also, have you treid following the step by step migration proccess [suggested in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration#v8_migration_procedure)?